# Codeigniter user_model Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I have a problem with user_model.php, below it's the errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: models/user_model.php
>
> Line Number: 18
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: \httpdocs\application\models\user_model.php
>   Line: 18
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: \httpdocs\application\controllers\user.php
>   Line: 9
>   Function: check_role
>
> File: \httpdocs\index.php
>   Line: 292
>   Function: require_once

user_model.php

```
public function check_role()
{
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_user_id');
    // get roles
    if ($user_id) {
        $row = $this->db->get_where(TBL_USERS, array('id' => $user_id))->row();
        $roles = $this->db->get_where(TBL_ROLES, array('id' => $row->role_id))->row_array();
        foreach ($roles as $key => $value) {
            $this->session->set_userdata($key, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

what is wrong with foreach?

Comment: `var_dump($roles)` and see what you are getting.

Comment: what you are trying  to assign in session?

Comment: @b0s3 where to put the `var_dump($roles)`...

Comment: After `$roles = $this->db......`.

Comment: it show me the text: `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `count($roles)` before `foreach()`.

```
public function check_role()
{
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_user_id');
    // get roles
    if ($user_id) {
        $row = $this->db->get_where(TBL_USERS, array('id' => $user_id))->row();
        $roles = $this->db->get_where(TBL_ROLES, array('id' => $row->role_id))->row_array();
        if(count($roles)>0)
        {
            foreach ($roles as $key => $value) {
               $this->session->set_userdata($key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, with count($roles) disappear the error but, the login part i can't see it anymore...

Comment: `print_r($roles);` before if condition and paste the result here.

Comment: `A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: roles

Filename: models/user_model.php

Line Number: 15`

Comment: That means `roles` variable is not holding any data.

Comment: What i can do to fix that?!